# MSSQL : Incorrect syntax near '!'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows
FROM "tbltasks"
WHERE "status" = 1
  AND CASE WHEN rel_type='project'
        AND rel_id IN (SELECT project_id
                      FROM tblproject_settings
                      WHERE project_id = rel_id
                       AND "name" = 'hide_tasks_on_main_tasks_table'
                       AND value=1)
       THEN rel_type != 'project'
       ELSE 1 = 1 END
```

I'm working on an Existing Project , I'm converting the queries from MySQL to MsSQL , when i Execute this Query it gives :

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '!'.
```

I'm Stuck in this Query for a Whole Week and Can't Find where the Problem is Coming from , I Really don't Know what to Do.

Comment: I believe the ISO standard SQL not equal operator is `<>` rather than `!=`.

Comment: Whitespace is free, you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, fix the quoting, which is probably not needed.  Second, the problem is probably the boolean expression in the `CASE/THEN`.  You can instead use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows
FROM tbltasks
WHERE status = 1 AND
      (CASE WHEN rel_type = 'project' AND
                 rel_id IN (SELECT project_id
                            FROM tblproject_settings
                            WHERE project_id = rel_id AND
                                  name = 'hide_tasks_on_main_tasks_table' AND
                                  value = 1
                           )
            THEN 0 ELSE 1
       END) = 1
```

I'm not a fan of using `CASE` expressions in `WHERE` clauses, so I would recommended rewriting that code.  However, for the sake of consistency between the queries in the two databases, I would wait to make such improvements until all the code works.

Comment: Sir Thank you so much i just executed it and it worked , Thank you so much , you're a Life Saver , God Bless U Sir